# Sennheiser 151 headset; microphone not working when using the native connector (without USB adapter) - why?

Tags: windows-7, usb, microphone, headphones, headset

when I am directly connecting the headset (Sennheiser 151) with my Dell XPS 15 laptop without using the little plug-to-USB-adapter (SpeedLink SL-8850-SBK VIGO USB Soundcard (is what the tiny label on it reads)) then the sound is even better than with using the little USB adapter but unfortunately the microphone stops working.

Currently I am on Windows 7 x64 SP1. Any ideas how to get the microphone working? - Expess your suggestions in simple language please, I am not a techie ;-)

Regards

Comment: Have you made sure that you fully pressed it into the socket?

Comment: yes, its as deep in the socket as the audio one is in the audio output

Comment: make sure it is not muted and IS selected as recording device.

Comment: If the plug is a normal headphone one (3.5mm with two black bands), then it doesn't carry a microphone signal.

Comment: i see, then it apparently doesn't carry a microphone signal :-/

Answer (score 0):

Be sure it is not muted (very close to volume control). If that isn't the issue, ensure in settings that it is selected as the microphone output (open Speech in Control Panel).